# What happened to the last vial from the Well of Eternity?

Tags: warcraft

I am trying to find out what happened to the last of the seven vials Illidan took from the Well of Eternity.

To the best of my knowledge he poured three into Lake Hyjal, one was taken by Dath'Remar Sunstrider and later used to create the Sunwell, and he gave one each to Lady Vashj and Kael'thas (later collected by PCs during The Burning Crusade).

But I can find no cannon explanation of what happened to the final vial.

The closest I can find is speculation that it was used in the Black Temple to power the source he fed to the demons to break their addiction to the legions magic (this speculation all seems to come from the warlock Green fire quest line).  Has there been any confirmed in-cannon evidence pointing to it's fate (short stories, novels, comics, etc...)?

Comment: I assume it's still concealed away somewhere. Regarding the well of fel energy in The Black Temple, that was already there before Illidan. The dialogue clearly states that the Legion's reward to Illidan for his service was to allow him access to the well, although he ended up taking it by force anyway. Therefore Illidan himself did not need to unlock it.

Comment: Maybe, but there are differing accounts about what is actually under the reliquary and what it's source may be (the obvious ones that come to mind are is it left over from before Karabor fell, or was it something that happened after Magtheridon took over the temple.)

Comment: Another consideration is that the waters appear to emanate pure arcane energy, not fel. I would speculate that the BT energy is from a different source, but that still leaves the question of where the last vial is.